# ExtJS how to set up an action after two asynchronous events

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two stores with `autoload: true` being loaded with data. I want to fill my UI after **both** of these have loaded. I am following the MVC architecture, so in my Controller, I am trying to do something like this:

```
store1.on('load', me.setUpIfBothStoresReady, me);
store2.on('load', me.setUpIfBothStoresReady, me);

setUpIfBothStoresReady: function() {
    if(store1.isSuccessfullyLoaded() && store2.isSuccessfullyLoaded()) {
        // do work
    }
}
```

The problem is that at this point, either one or both store could already be loaded. Apart from controlling the load on these stores manually, is there some design pattern I can use to do work only after both are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like whenjs with defered events.

https://github.com/cujojs/when/wiki/Examples

Or write your own:

```
loadStores: function() {
    ...
    me.loaded = 0;
    store1.on('load', me.setUpIfBothStoresReady, me);
    store2.on('load', me.setUpIfBothStoresReady, me);
},

...

setUpIfBothStoresReady: function() {

    ++this.loaded;
    if (this.loaded == 2) {
        //do work
    }
}
```

if you have a few stores, will be better use array.